# How to disable buttons after fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have two buttons in my app. One open fragment (fragment button) and one open activity (activity button). After click on the fragment button and immediately click on the activity button, the fragment is open and the activity opening after him. There is a solution to my problem without disabling the activity button after click the fragment button.

This is my fragment transaction:

```
 searchAddressFragment = new SearchAddressFragment();
            searchAddressFragment.setArguments(args);
            searchAddressFragment.setItRangeAddress(isItRangeAddress);
            ft.replace(drawerLayout.getId(), searchAddressFragment).addToBackStack("searchAddressFragment").commit();
```

Comment: Can you please post code of onClick() of buttons that opens fragment & activity?

Comment: you should manage one flag for button click.
but first you check why activity was open when you click on **Fragment Button**

Comment: you should use a handler for manage click flag like set isButtonClicked=true after 200 milisec

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable buttons, you should come up with workaround using a flag like this;

```
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isButtonClicked){
                 startYourFragmentTransaction();
            }
            isButtonClicked = true;
        }
    });

secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isButtonClicked){
                startYourActivity();
            }
            isButtonClicked = true;
        }
    });
```

Note. After transaction you might need change back `isButtonClicked` flag to false